# Bash history - multi-line strings causing multi-line history

Tags: bash

I prefer having all shell commands on a single line in `~/.bash_history` so I've made sure to set `cmdhist` (`shopt -s cmdhist`) in `~/.bashrc`.

This works properly:

```sh
$ for x in 1 2; do
> echo "$x"
> done
1
2
$ history -a
$ tail -n2  ~/.bash_history
for x in 1 2; do echo "$x"; done
history -a
```

However, when entering multi-line strings, they seem to always be added on multiple lines in the history:

```sh
$ echo "3
> 4"
3
4
$ echo '5
> 6'
5
6
$ history -a
$ tail -n5 ~/.bash_history
echo "3
4"
echo '5
6'
history -a
```

This tends to mess up scripts that parse the `~/.bash_history` file and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> searching (ex: searching for `6` finds `6'` instead of the full command)

Is there any way to adjust this behavior? Is it working as expected or is it a bug?

Bash version: `GNU bash v5.0.17(1)-release`

Comment: Can you see if `lithist` is turned on ? If not try doing `shopt -s lithist`

Comment: `lithist` was off. I turned it on and it didn't seem to make any difference

Comment: Can you restart your interactive shell once and see if the lines are saved now properly (with `lithist` still on) and also what's the value of `HISTTIMEFORMAT`?

Comment: Loaded up a fresh interactive shell with `lithist` on and the results are the same. `$HISTTIMEFORMAT` is unset.

Comment: `lishist` seems to modify *code* formatting, but not actual *values*. At first glance, asking that `lithist` store a multiline string value as, e.g., `$'3\n4'` doesn't sound like a bad feature request.

Comment: One of the best in-depth multi-line command history summeries, I have ever found, that should explain everything you want or need to know...
   https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/353407/68648